# If not exists, checking for table by name

Tags: mysql

I want to create idempotent scripts for agile database development with mysql. Here is a link if you want to see about it: 
http://haacked.com/archive/2006/07/05/bulletproofsqlchangescriptsusinginformation_schemaviews.aspx/

drop table if exists is so wrong for this. I am looking for something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'foo'
    AND table_name = 'customer'
    LIMIT 1;
)
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE customer(n int);
END
```

If it helps, I am looking for a functionality of:

```
If Not exists something
then
    statement1
    statement2
    ...
    statementN
else
    do nothing
fi
```

Comment: You should be able to do this in a stored procedure.

Comment: No need for a stored procedure; this is a basic piece of functionality that comes with `CREATE TABLE`. OP, read the manual!!

Comment: That doesn't work boundary for what I asked.   The script needs to be idempotent doesn't do.  This isn't a bull in the china shop.   If it doesn't exist, execute N steps not just one.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer
    (n int);
```

See [MySQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)